# How to make a GameObject occasionally change direction in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to create a periodic timer in Unity, so that I can create a GameObject that randomly moves around. Unfortunately, with my current code, the GameObject goes in a constant direction and doesn't ever update to change the direction. I believe that it might not be changing because the coroutine might only be called once, but I'm not exactly sure how to create a timer that can do this. I've been searching for a while online, but I haven't found anything yet. Here's the main code that has been causing the issue:

```
   public float speed;
   public float wanderDegrees;

    void Update() 
    {

        if (gameObject.name == "Enemy_R")
        {
            StartCoroutine("RandomMovements");
        }
    }

    IEnumerator RandomMovements()
    {
            float angle = Mathf.PerlinNoise(-wanderDegrees, wanderDegrees) * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
            Vector2 direction = new Vector2(Mathf.Sin(angle), -Mathf.Cos(angle));
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            Vector2 velocity = direction * speed;
            transform.Translate(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public float speed = 1f;
public float wanderDegrees = 45f;

Vector2 _velocity;

void Start() {
    // Don't check the game object's name here. Just put this component
    // on ONLY the enemy that's supposed to use it, and not on the others.
    // if (gameObject.name == "Enemy_R")

    // Don't look up your coroutine by its name - that's unnecessarily slow.
    StartCoroutine(ChooseRandomDirectionsPeriodically());
}

// You want to move every frame, not just when you pick a new direction, 
// so put that in Update.
void Update() {
    transform.Translate(_velocity * Time.deltaTime);
}

IEnumerator ChooseRandomDirectionsPeriodically()
{
    // Use a while loop to repeat this behaviour over and over again at intervals.
    while (true) {
        // The way you were using noise here was nonsensical. 
        // Let's use a random die roll instead.
        float angle = Random.Range(-wanderDegrees, wanderDegrees) * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
        Vector2 direction = new Vector2(Mathf.Sin(angle), -Mathf.Cos(angle));
        // Cache the velocity in a member variable to be used in Update.
        _velocity = direction * speed;

        // Wait at the end of the loop, after we've done all our work.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    }
}
```